# Is there any similarity in the concept behind Java Thread Pooling and Java EventQueue in AWT?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, awt, threadpool

As far as I know, Thread Pooling is a process that reuses already created Threads in the Wait mode and assigns them a task. The number of such threads are specified during Pool creation.

And in Java AWT, EventQueue does something similar. It posts a Runnable Swing object at the end of the Event Queue, and this object is processed after the previous objects' processing is over.

So, is EventQueue a kind of Thread Pooling done in AWT ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: The short answer is no - The `EventQueue` is processed by a **single** thread (the Event Dispatching Thread).  When it pops a `Runnable` of the queue, it simply calls the `run` method, it otherwise process the event based on the internal requirements of the EDT

Comment: Thanks a lot @MadProgrammer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Not even vaguely. Your ThreadPool description is about right, but I don't see why you think this is anything like the event queue.

The event queue is basically a collection of stuff on one thread to make sure certain operations only happen on the correct thread. There is no "pool" of event queues or similar.

Comment: Thanks @John3126 ! I think I get what you said. So the EventQueue is a Queue that is maintained on a single thread ?

Comment: Any thread can add to it (that is how a thread gets something to run on the Event Dispatch Thread), but it is only "used" by the EDT.

Answer (score 0):

Yes `awt.EventQueue` can be considered as a single thread pool executor. Having single thread is to exclude parallelism while modifying screen image.

If you use Akka actors, you can creates special dispatcher which runs actors on the `awt.EventQueue`. Actors with such dispatcher can modify GUI elements.